# CakePHP hash extract from JSON data

Tags: php, json, cakephp, hash

I am trying to extract some part of a JSON formatted string in CakePHP using the [Hash::extract](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) method .

Here is the JSON string:

```
[[{"name":"Atkins Global","y":{"count":96,"type":"1"}},
{"name":"HFT","y":{"count":444,"type":"1"}},
{"name":"Catalyst","y":{"count":8,"type":"1"}},
{"name":"BGL","y":{"count":2,"type":"1"}}]]
```

Here is what I used in CakePHP to retrieve the above JSON:

```
debug(json_encode(Hash::extract($data['type'], '{s}')));
```

`$data['type']` holds the data above.

Is there a way I can grab the `type` values only? Not sure how I can do this in CakePHP. Would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: You should show the original data instead of something extracted (and please in a formatted fashion, reading nested structured is really hard when they are being flattened like that).

Answer (score 0):

From an [answer](http://aerocoding.com/en/question/47/How-to-Hash-extract-value-from-JSON-data-utility-class) by Roberto Atkinson, you have to do `json_decode()` first to convert a JSON string to a PHP array, instead of encoding an array to JSON. Reference: [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

In your case, try:

```
//from JSON string to PHP array; force returned objects to be converted into associative arrays
$data['type'] = json_decode($data['type'], true); 

//now you can extract type values from data 
$output = Hash::extract($data['type'], '{s}'));
```

In addition, according to [CakePHP official API documentation: Hash::extract()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Utility.Hash.html#_extract), the first parameter should be an array.

> Parameters (array|ArrayAccess $data The data to extract from.,  string $path The path to extract.)